# How to modify and manipulate a shiny reactive object/data frame

Tags: r, shiny

I have a really simple csv file.

```
> head(data)
         X  Y
1 1/1/1900  1
2 1/2/1900  2
3 1/3/1900  4
4 1/4/1900  8
5          16
```

And I have a shinny app that plots that file after the user uploads the file

this is the code

```
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
              multiple = TRUE,
              accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv")),
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250))
              )
      ),

      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2)


  data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if(!is.null(inFile)){
      read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    
    }
  })


  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(data())


    plot(data()$X, data()$Y)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My question is how you modify the reactive object data()?, lets say I want to change the column X to a date column using the as.Date command and then I want to remove line 5 because it has an empty value and then multiply column Y by 10 and after I do all that then plot the graph? thanks for the help

Comment: you can assign it to another object, modify it and plot it. For example: `dat <- data(); dat$X <- as.Date(dat$X)`...`plot(dat$X, dat$Y)`

Comment: Thanks a million works like a charm, if you want to put it as an answer I will accept it, and thanks again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign your reactive object to a variable.

```
data <- reactive({
  inFile <- input$file1
  if(!is.null(inFile)) {
     read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    
  }
})

dat <- data()
dat$X <- as.Date(dat$X)
dat <- dat[-5,]
dat$Y <- dat$Y * 10

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({    
  plot(dat$X, dat$Y)
})
```